# Retrieving DocumentFilter.FilterBypass

Tags: java, swing

I am making a custom `DocumentFilter`. For that purpose my class is overriding the methods replace and remove.Once I make some checks in those methods I call super.replace , super.remove.

Although I also want to use replace and remove without invoking  the same methods local KeyEvents invoke, for example when I receive a message. For that purpose I have this method :

```
public void replaceUpdate(InputCommand cmd)  {    
    super.replace(hereGoesFB, cmd.offset, cmd.length, cmd.text, null);
}
```

The problem is I need DocumentFilter.FilterBypass in order to make call to super.replace() on the method above but I can't find how to use this static class. Is there someway to retrieve it from my current `DocumentFilter`? Thanks

Comment: As a way around it I am inserting a String on component creation and getting the FilterBypass from there. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: When you call replaceUpdate()?

Comment: Messages with InputCommand are send over network. When I receive such a message I call replace/remove to change the text of local component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved, I believe in the end I did not need to get the filter, cant remember but should close question.